# SQL: exclude code

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I don't understand what's the meaning of this clause:

```
cn = (select count(c1.challenge_id) from challenges as c1 
group by c1.hacker_id
order by count(c1.challenge_id) desc limit 1) "?
```

Whole SQL:

```
select c.hacker_id, h.name, count(c.challenge_id) as cn
from challenges as c join hackers as h 
on c.hacker_id = h.hacker_id
group by c.hacker_id having 
cn = 
(select count(c1.challenge_id) from challenges as c1 
 group by c1.hacker_id
 order by count(c1.challenge_id) desc limit 1) 
or 
cn not in 
(select count(c2.challenge_id) from challenges as c2 
 group by c2.hacker_id having
 c.hacker_id != c2.hacker_id)
order by cn desc, c.hacker_id
```

Comment: May I ask what the actual purpose of that query should be? I just looked quickly into it but I think it might give you different results on different databases (or even same db) - for example if you'd deploy your stuff from development to production. The reason is that the order of the results of the main select may change ...

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(c1.challenge_id) from challenge
```

It counts the number of challenges.

```
select count(c1.challenge_id) from challenges as c1 
group by c1.hacker_id
```

It counts challenges created by hacker.

E.g Hacker A has created 56 challenges
    Hacker B has create 36 challenges

```
order by count(c1.challenge_id) desc limit 1
```

It orders the count of challenges by hackers in descending order. Limit 1 picks up the first element in this order.

It's a query of finding the maximum challenges.

Comment: Thanks. But if two people have created the same maximum challenges, what will be returned? In my understanding, limit 1 will just return one maximum people's name, how about the other one?

Comment: Actually it's just find the maximum challenges created by any hacker. See select has just count in query. Updated the answer.